# /usr/local/bin/node: not found

Tags: unix, npm

I kept getting the error above, when I do which node I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/node
```

so in my .bash_profile, I've put in:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

but still the error doesn't go away

Comment: Try the following things: `file /usr/bin/node`; `file /usr/local/bin/node` and add the output to your question.

Comment: What do you get if you `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Are you saying that `which node` gave you the error `/usr/bin/node`?

Comment: You'll also need to ensure that `/usr/local/bin` is in the `PATH`.

Comment: @xonegirlz, it would help to know what command produces the error, `/usr/local/bin/node: not found`.  It would also help if you had the exact error message.  Also note that changes to `.bash_profile` only take effect when either you restart your shell or you re-run the commands in `.bash_profile`.  A quick and easy way to do this is to run the command, `source .bash_profile`.

Answer (score 16):

If you can **not** or do **not** want to change the program you are running. (you could just change the /usr/local/bin/node to /usr/bin/node in that program), an alternative solution is to create a link from your node installation to the path it is trying to load it from.

Run this as root:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

Where the first path parameter is the **source**, and second path parameter as **destination**

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly normal and it is not an error. When you run `which`, the result will be the location of the program if it is successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to run node.js ?, in ubuntu 14.04 the node.js is installed at usr/bin/nodejs. So to run the programs you need use `nodejs my_file.js` instead of node `node my_file.js` like windows operation system.

you can confirm it using the command `which` as said above.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
if you are using Node.js v17.9.1 on a MacBook pro lower version which does not accept other higher versions, then you should use the above link for your interpreter. #!/usr/bin/node will not work. this worked for me!